# Who is versed in the writing of svg images?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the svg code of the magnifier picture:

```
<path fill="none" d="M19.129,18.164l-4.518-4.52c1.152-1.373,1.852-3.143,1.852-5.077c0-4.361-3.535-7.896-7.896-7.896
                        c-4.361,0-7.896,3.535-7.896,7.896s3.535,7.896,7.896,7.896c1.934,0,3.705-0.698,5.078-1.853l4.52,4.519
                        c0.266,0.268,0.699,0.268,0.965,0C19.396,18.863,19.396,18.431,19.129,18.164z M8.567,15.028c-3.568,0-6.461-2.893-6.461-6.461
                        s2.893-6.461,6.461-6.461c3.568,0,6.46,2.893,6.46,6.461S12.135,15.028,8.567,15.028z">
                    </path>
```

The problem is that the picture climbs to the bottom, thereby pulling the rest of the elements, css parameters are not applied to it(padding). Below I will attach screenshots. Help to make so that the image was in the center vertically. Below is the code responsible for the buttons:

```
.svg-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
}

.svg-icon path,
.svg-icon polygon,
.svg-icon rect {
    fill: #00FF00;
}

.svg-icon circle {
    stroke: #00FF00;
    stroke-width: 1;
}
a.navbutton{ 
    display: flex;  
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: story_brush;
    text-align: center;    
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: #00FF00;
padding: 0px 20px;
```

}"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xMsA.png)

Comment: give the SVG code an appropriate viewBox

Comment: the relevant part of your code is missing. It would be nice to show the whole svg element, the one that is wrapping the path

Comment: <svg class="svg-icon navbutton" viewBox="-1 -1 22 22">